# How do I normalize a CSV list in to 2 or more separate files?

Tags: python, csv

I have a dataset (csv) of people and their voting locations like:

```
**Person | Voting Place | VP address | ....**

John Doe | Zoo | 123 fake street | ....

Jane Doe | Zoo | 123 fake street | ....

Joey Ramone | Park | 814 Real Street | ...
```

I'd like to normalize this data such that locations are pulled out into a separate list, deduped, and assigned an arbitrary ID#. The people are then stored in a separate file with a reference to the voting location ID# instead of the actual info.

I understand how to use python sets to dedupe a combination of columns and break them out in their own file. What I don't understand is how to I get/assign an ID of each element in the SET() list that I can use to refer back to it later? Can this be done on a single iteration through the csv such that *pseudocode*:

```
for row in file:
    person = [row[0], row[1]]
    voting_location = [row[2],row[3]]
    if voting_location not in unique_set:
        add to set
        get ID of element in set
        write location line in location file
    else: # location already in list so its a duplicate
        get id of location already in list
    append id to person_list
    write person line in person file
```

Is there a way to do this in pure python / csv or do I need to fire up a proper relational database to get the job done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a dictionary.  Use the voting location as keys and for the corresponding values, make a list of the voters who are registered there:

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict


data = OrderedDict()
with open('input.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    for row in reader:
        row = [e.strip() for e in row]
        person   = row[0]
        location = (row[1], row[2])

        if location not in data: data[location] = []

        data[location].append(person)

# Show voting places
print("Voting places (voting_place_id, voting_place):")
for (i,k) in enumerate(data):
    print("  %3d %s" % (i,k))
print("")

# Show voters
print("Voters (voting_place_id, person):")
for (i,k) in enumerate(data):
    for p in data[k]:
        print("  %3d %s" % (i,p))
print("")
```

Output:

```
Voting places (voting_place_id, voting_place):
    0 ('Voting Place', 'VP address')
    1 ('Zoo', '123 fake street')
    2 ('Park', '814 Real Street')

Voters (voting_place_id, person):
    0 Person
    1 John Doe
    1 Jane Doe
    2 Joey Ramone
```

There is no state saved between runs of this script, so if you run it with half your dataset once, then again with the rest, the same "place id"s will be re-used without any regard to the IDs that were generated the first run.

However, if you *append* data to your original data, and run the program again, the IDs generated from the first run will match the IDs generated from the second run, provided nothing changes in the rows that were present the first time (this is why we use an `OrderedDict` instead of a `dict`).

If you want persistent state, you could always [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) and `unpickle` the `data` dictionary between runs.  Or dump the ordered keys to a file, and initialize the `data` dictionary with those keys.

Comment: Thank you. I think you are on to a good solution with orderedDict.  Presumably if the location was already in the orderedDict, I could iterate over it to discover it's "row number". 

It did just occur to me that I could hash the concatenation of the location data and store the hash value in both the person and the location CSV. Each unique combo should produce the same hash value. Would that work?

Comment: Each unique pair *almost* definitely will produce a unique hash, but hash collisions are possible and need to be accounted for.  Dictionaries will handle this transparently to you, behind the scenes, so if you want to implement your own system wish hashes, you should at least check for hash collisions (maybe keep a list of previously generated hashes?).